# Unable to disable proposed updates (developer options)

Tags: official-repositories

I'm unable to uncheck "Pre-released updates" from Developer Options in "Software & Updates" application.

When I click to uncheck the system asks for my password and after that nothing happens.

Is it possible to unable by command line or editing some file?

[image: checkbox doesnt works]

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: After unchecking, what happens when you click on "Close"? Also, what do you mean by **"unable"**? Did you mean **"disable"** (since as per screenshot, it is already enabled). You can disable `-proposed` by removing lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` which contains `focal-proposed`. But if you're a beginner try avoiding manually editing that file.

Comment: Yes a mean disable.
When I click "close" it asks to update the list, but when I open it again the screen is still marked.
I believe it must be just an interface bug, I checked the sources.list and there is nothing about the "proposed" channel.
Thanks @Kulfy, I am calm knowing that it is outside the source.list

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my main machine having 20.04. APT considers only sources.list and files in sources.list,d as reposiories/software sources. Did you click on "Reload" after clicking on "Close" button? What is the output of `grep -R proposed /etc/apt/sources.list*`?

Comment: @Kulfy yes I click on Reload before close
And misse the others files...
The grep result:
```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed.list:deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ focal-proposed restricted multiverse main universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed.list.save:deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ focal-proposed restricted multiverse main universe
```
If I delete proposed.list and proposed.list.save must resolve?

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. This is weird since the repositories in `sources.list.d` folder are generally under Other Software tab. And Developer Options and Ubuntu Software in Software & Updates app can modify `sources.list`. If that solves your problem, I'd encourage you to post an answer explaining how you added that, encountered the issue and removed that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Delete theses files ()

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed.list.save
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed.list
```

Restart the system
Go to "Software & Updates" and the "Pre-released updates" will be unchecked.

Thanks @Kulfy

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and delete

- ubuntu-[your version name]-proposed.list
- ubuntu-[your version name]-proposed.list.save

using sudo rm as mentioned.